# MySQL with php variable trouble

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with putting a php variable into a mysql query.

For example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE title LIKE '%ipod%'");
```

That works, but

```
$key = "ipod";
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE title LIKE '%$key%'");
```

That doesn't work.

I might be doing it wrong though. If the above is the correct way to do it, then maybe another part of my script has a typo or something like that.
Any help would be great.

Comment: You are not selecting anything.

Comment: Sidenote: the `mysql_` commands are officially discouraged, you should start using [PDO](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_`](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: I would assume since you say the first one works (which it will not as it is written), maybe echo $key and see if a problem lies there

Comment: This is extremely dangerous to do without [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: With your approach, you should read about SQL Injection(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and the security risks that arise with your approach.

Answer (score 3):

Your not selecting anything:

```
"SELECT * FROM listings WHERE title LIKE '%$key%'"
```

notice the `*`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the * was a wildcard. I've always used it to select all the rows in a table that match the criteria. Would it not, in this case select all the rows from the "listing" table where the title is like '%$key%'. My apologies if this is a dumb question. I'm not very familiar with SQL syntax. I just need to know if I've been doing it wrong all this time.

Comment: The query is not correctly produced. This was nothing to do with selection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $key = "ipod";
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE title LIKE '%".$key."%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$key = "ipod";
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE title LIKE '$key'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($results);
echo "Received " . $num . "rows of results";

While ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = "ipod";
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE title LIKE '".$key."'");
```

Comment: That won't work because there are no quotes around the value of `$key`